# Open multiple urls in same new tab javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, tabs

I am writing a javascript open multiple URLs on the same tab. I know how to open a link in a new tab.

```
window.open(your_url,"_blank")
```

However, my client wants me to open just one tab with multiple URLs.
Imagine you have a javascript

```
var urlList=['https://www.google.com', 'www.youtube.com']
```

I want to open then one by one on the same new tabs with interval 10secs. 
First, I do

```
window.open(urlList[0],"_blank")
```

But then if I am still doing that for the second one, it opens another new tab, not on the old one. Any knows how to specify the opened tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are opening using [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) method it will return the window object of the newly opened tab, use it for updating URL after 10 seconds. For providing delay use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method.

```
// website lists
const urlList = ['https://www.google.com', 'http://www.youtube.com']

// open the first url and cache the window object reference
const win = window.open(urlList[0], "_blank")

// variable for keeping track of array position(urls)
let i = 1;

// create interval with 10seconds delay and keep 
// interval reference to clear the event in future
let int = setInterval(() => {
  // update the location with next array value
  win.location = urlList[i];
  // check value of i and increment, if reached the max value then clear the interval
  if (i++ >= urlList.length) clearInterval(int)
}, 10000)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a sample code.

```
    async function navigate() {
 var _window = window.open("","_blank")
 var urlList=['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.youtube.com'];   
 for (var url of urlList) {     
    _window.location.replace(url);
    await sleep(10000);
 }   
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd want to do this. Don't. ***It's super annoying.*** But if you must, the following works and has been tested in chrome (and *only* in chrome)

A couple of things to note:

1. This will not bypass pop-up blockers. Users **must allow it**.
2. This does not technically use the "*same*" tab. Old one is closed and new opened quick enough user won't notice.

```js
var myWindow;

let urls = ["https://stackoverflow.com", "https://stackexchange.com/"];
let counter = 0;
let openWindow;

function openWin(url) {
    openWindow = window.open(url, "_blank");
}

function closeWin(){
    openWindow.close();
}

setInterval(function(){
    if(openWindow) closeWin();
    openWin(urls[counter]);
    counter++;
}, 10000)
```